# JS - submitting through javascript does not pass post variables

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using Pure JS to first prevent the form from submitting then I have some validation code and finally automatic submission but the data is not passing from client side to server script.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chat Room</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="add-nick">
        <h3>Enter Your Name</h3>
        <form action="chat.php" method="post" id="add-nicki">
            <input type="text" placeholder="At least 6 alphabets e.g. Jackson" class="text" name="name" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" name="btnsubmit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var regexp = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z]+$"),
        elem = this.elements[0],
        value = elem.value;
        if(regexp.test(value) && typeof value != "null" && value.length > 5) {
            elem.className = "text correct";
            var formElem = this;
            setTimeout(function() { formElem.submit(); }, 0);
        }
        else elem.className = "text wrong";
    };
};
```

The PHP file:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    echo $_SESSION['name'];
}
else {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name']))
        echo "Header";
    else
        echo $_SESSION['name'];
}


?>
```

Is there something wrong or JS `submit` function is not functioning properly ?

Comment: Why not only cancel the event in case the text is *wrong*?

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus You mean `return false;` ? Everything on client-side is working as expected but just variables are not passing. I have searched SO and Google but all have weird solutions. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request parameter corresponding to a submit button is only passed if the form is submitted as a result of clicking that button. That's not the case here since you suppress the original form submit (the one triggered by the button), then later call `formElem.submit()` from JavaScript; no button click means no request parameter, and therefore `isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])` in your PHP script won't ever return true.

One solution might be to add the `btnsubmit` parameter to the form's action before submitting it:

```
formElem.action += (formElem.action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?btnsubmit=Submit' : '&btnsubmit=Submit');
```

Comment: Ahh! Nice but cannot it be async so user cannot see that I have GET request for button or I have to keep it?

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar You could create a hidden input and append it to the form to achieve the same result, if you wanted to. Or you could do an AJAX form submission. There are a number of potential solutions, I provided the simplest one, I'll leave it to you to decide which works best for you.

Comment: ahh! This been so long that I have worked with forms and pure JS. I didn't realized that I can use hidden input. Thanks. You saved my time.